# WPF ComboBoxItem not showing until mouseover

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml, combobox

I have a ComboBox with unbound items as shown in the XAML below.  When the window containing this ComboBox opens, the ComboBox appears as if no ComboBoxItem is selected (even though `SelectedIndex = 0`) until the ComboBox or *any other* input control in the window is moused over. This mouseover seems to trigger an event causing the ComboBox to redraw/refresh, revealing the selection.

```
  <Style x:Key="LineStyle" TargetType="Rectangle">
    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="3"/>
    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="4"/>
  </Style>

    <ComboBox VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectedIndex="0">
      <ComboBoxItem ToolTip="Solid" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Canvas Width="69" Height="11">
          <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource LineStyle}" Width="69" Canvas.Left="0" />
        </Canvas>
      </ComboBoxItem>
      <ComboBoxItem ToolTip="Dash" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Canvas Width="69" Height="11">
          <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource LineStyle}" Width="11" Canvas.Left="0" />
          <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource LineStyle}" Width="11" Canvas.Left="19" />
          <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource LineStyle}" Width="11" Canvas.Left="38" />
          <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource LineStyle}" Width="11" Canvas.Left="57" />
        </Canvas>
      </ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
```

I had this exact same problem previously with a ComboBox with unbound items consisting of a `StackPanel` containing an `Image` and `TextBlock`.  The workaround there was to bind the items rather than "hardcode" them in XAML, but that is not an option now.  Is there an XAML solution to this blank ComboBox problem?

If I instead just use simple text-based ComboBoxItem like:

```
  <ComboBoxItem Content="Solid" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
```

everything works fine.  I am using the default ComboBox template in Visual Studio.

Comment: Works fine for me. What's in your LineStyle?

Comment: @Clemens - Question updated to include the style.

Comment: are you going to add something more? this works just fine, the problem you have lies in other parts of your code

Comment: @Milan - No doubt there is nothing wrong with the XAML above.  We have stripped out other XAML and that did not resolve the issue.  What I am hoping for is that someone has experienced this issue before and knows a quick fix for it, whether that is an XAML solution, system/display setting, etc.